# CSS transition reverse effect

Tags: css, menu, transition

I have transition in css for dropdown menu, on hover scaleY(0) to scaleY(1). Menu drop down smoothly. My question is how to reverse this effect, when currsor is no longer hovering parent (and child) menu needs to hide self with animatioin, not just disappear. Here is css:

```
nav ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 116px;
    height: 126px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;

    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);

    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

ul li:hover > .menu_sub {
    visibility: visible;

    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add transition is normal and hovered state it will return on original place

```
nav ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 116px;
    height: 126px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 63px;

    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);

    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease;
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}

ul li:hover > .menu_sub {
    visibility: visible;

    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);


    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s ease;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease;
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

Comment: I did that at first place, but it didn't work. Problem was with visibility. When button is not hovered visibility was automatically set to hidden. I solved that, thanks for quick answer.